# Can't get saved checkmarks to appear on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a UITableView where a user can tap on a cell and a checkmark appears on the cell accessory view.  When the cell is tapped, the index path is saved to an array and the array is saved to disk.

When I leave and go back into the view controller, I am unable to have the checkmarks reappear on the UITableView.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"selectedCells"];
    self.retrievedIndexPaths = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:    

    [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data], nil];

    NSLog(@"%@", self.retrievedIndexPaths);

}
```

Probably where I'm doing something wrong:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.categoriesArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    for (NSIndexPath *retrievedIndexPath in self.retrievedIndexPaths)
    {
        if (retrievedIndexPath == indexPath)
        {   // Never hits here
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }

return cell;

}
```

Save checkmark data:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [self.selectedRowsArray addObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self.selectedIndexPathsMutableArray addObject:self.lastIndexPath];

}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [self.selectedRowsArray removeObject:cell.textLabel.text];
    [self.selectedIndexPathsMutableArray removeObject:indexPath];
}
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

NSLog(@"%@", self.selectedRowsArray);
NSLog(@"%@", self.selectedIndexPathsMutableArray);
}

#pragma mark - UIBUTTON

- (IBAction)doneButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"button pressed");

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.selectedIndexPathsMutableArray] forKey:@"selectedCells"];
    [defaults synchronize];


    [[PFUser currentUser] setObject:self.selectedRowsArray forKey:@"interests"];
    [[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use NSKeyedArchiver? You can use setObject directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An indexPath his an object, so you shouldn't test for equality with "==". There's also no need to loop through the array, just use containsObject,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = self.categoriesArray[indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    if ([self.retrievedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath]){ 
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but still doesn't work.  Breakpoint never hits the cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark line.

Comment: @MayYang, then something must be wrong with retrievedIndexPaths. What does the log of that show?

Comment: 2015-04-04 16:49:43.494 speeddate[1065:19761] (
        (
        "<NSIndexPath: 0x7fc528438670> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
        "<NSIndexPath: 0x7fc528419a10> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}"
    )

Comment: @MayYang I can't tell from that print out if you have a typo in it or not -- it shows 2 parentheses at the beginning and only one at the end. Which is correct?

Comment: I checked and there's another ) at the end.  So 2 parentheses at the beginning and 2 at the end.

Comment: @MayYang, OK, so that's the problem. You have an array inside another array -- the outer array has just one object, and that is another array.

Comment: Thanks, I caught that when you asked me about the parentheses.  I guess this is happening within my viewWillAppear, correct (if you look at my original code I posted)?  Is the way I am retrieving my data from NSUserDefaults wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74496/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-may-yang).

Answer (score 0):

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark